# How can I check if a file contains only integers?

Tags: c++, qt, file, integer

In my project I need to upload a file and check that inside it there is an integer (positive or negative) for each line so that it can be represented within a vector.

Since I am working on QT and C++ I have considered two proposals, but both when I insert a number in the file for example "35.2" with a comma and I press the start button the program crashes.

Is there a better solution to mitigate the problem? I am attaching one of the solution that I was evaluating.

```
QFile file_in(file_name);

file_in.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream in(&file_in);
int elem;
int pos = 0;
QString s;
QIntValidator valid(-999, 999, this);

while(!in.atEnd())
{
    in >> elem;
    s = QString::number(elem);
    if(!valid.validate(s,pos))
    {
        v.clear();
        QMessageBox msg(this);
        msg.setText("Input non valido");
        msg.exec();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        v.push_back(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can try with [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)

Comment: You already assigned to int before checking it. Also question needs more clarification. Could you list what you want to accept as `int` ? How your file is structured ? Sample file would be good.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
The file is something like this:
-2
24
4
71
.... on for each line

Comment: _" the program crashes."_ : where does it crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to read the file line by line and check if the current line is convertible to an integer.

Qt already provides a lot of convenience methods. For instance, you would be interested by [`QByteArray::toInt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toInt).

Hence a solution could be:

```
bool validate(const QString & file_name)
{
    QFile in_f(file_name);
    if(!in_f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return false;

    bool is_valid = true;
    while(is_valid && !in_f.atEnd())
    {
        QByteArray line = in_f.readLine();
        line.toInt(&is_valid); // is_valid is set to false if the conversion failed
    }
    return is_valid;
}
```

This way there is no crash. If each line contains an integer, it will return `true`, otherwise, if at least one line contains something else (string, double, ...), it will return `false`.

As implemented here, if the file is empty, the function will return `true`. Of course you can add a check for this case if you want to return `false` instead.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the doc about validate method here:

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qintvalidator.html#validate

you are using a criteria for valid inputs as `valid(-999, 999, this);`

so if the list in the file is holding a row with 1000, using a **toInt** method will return you a false positive result!

the result is not just True or False like you may think...

you actually get:

[image]